# Stop Firefox JavaScript alert from beeping

Tags: linux, firefox, fedora

When a JavaScript calls the `alert()` method, Firefox send out a BEEP in my headphones. Does any one know how to stop that sound?

I am running the newest Fedora Linux with Firefox 3.6.16 using Kde as desktop environment.

Comment: Mute your sound.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, You need to execute this command:

> xset b off

This command will stop all the bell sent to your headphone or to your cpu.

Comment: Nope, don't work. Alert still make a sound -(

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but it looks like it uses libcanberra for audio playback (and "sound themes"); you can try adding:

```
gtk-enable-event-sounds=false
gtk-enable-input-feedback-sounds=false
```

to your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file (make it if it doesn't exist).

Note that gnome instead uses GSettings for these preferences; if you use a Gnome desktop, try looking in `org.gnome.desktop.sound` in `dconf-editor` or similar gsettings frontends.

`gtk-error-bell=false` did not help on my system, but I have it set, too, for other reasons.

You can also try to replace the file `dialog-warning.oga` (on my system) with a silent audio clip. On my Debian system, the full path is `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/dialog-warning.oga`.

Note that these will disable that beep noise system-wide. I haven't found a way to make Firefox behave nicely on its own, yet.